# width:100% vs max-width: 100%

Tags: html, css

Could width:100% and max-width:100% be used interchangeably if any of them is used just once?

For example I get the same results with:

```
img{
    width:100%;
}
```

and with:

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If your images are always larger than the element they are within the two rules will appear to behave the same. If an img is smaller than the parent element than the first rule will stretch it to the full width of its parent. The second rule will not.

Comment: Yes, I tested and it works as you described it. So I should use width:100% if I want to be absolutely sure that my image will be as wide as the parent element, but max-width:100% if I want to ensure that it's not going to stretch beyond its actual size?

Comment: Pretty much. Personally, I've never had a good reason to apply `width: 100%` to images because I don't want them to blur if the parent element grows wider than the image. Also, be aware that globally setting `max-width: 100%` can have unexpected side effects in 3rd party widgets and potentially your own content. I've had problems with Google Maps for example. Instead I suggest creating a class like `img.responsive` with that rule, or scoping it to a content area via a selector like `.blog-post img`.