# In CSS, what is the difference between image width:100% and max-width:100%?

Tags: css

I always used to write the following, mainly for mobile templates:

```
img{
    width:100%;
}
```

But, I see everywhere that, the following is used:

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Surely, the two pieces of CSS, do exactly the same thing? Or am I going mad?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255410/width100-vs-max-width-100

Comment: Possible duplicate of [width:100% vs max-width: 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255410/width100-vs-max-width-100)

Comment: Yes. But, the answers to that question, did not clarify the issue, because those that answered, started refering to 'px' units rather than %. The 'px' part totally makes sense, but I cannot get my head around the % part, with respect to width & max-width

Answer (score 1):

for example IMG with `{ width: 32px; }` it mean `32px = 100%` then `200% = 64px`
so `max-width` will be `<= 32` only.

Comment: So, are you saying that if the physical dimension of the image is less than 32px, the image will display at its physical width, rather than expand to the edges of its container?

Comment: But, I thought that the % was relative to its parent container and not relative to the image itself?

Comment: I just found this link that verifies that % image width is a % of its container element, not a % of the images actual width:  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/width/

Comment: Can you add a demo with this? I'm sure this won't work.